# Bind event for dynamic added elements in Jquery not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-events

I have added `Address`,`city` and `locality` using jQuery in a dynamic added div element where the binding event is not working as expected:
I have below jQuery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var counter = 0;
        $(document).on('click', '#addButton', function (e) {
            if (counter > 19) {
                alert("Only 20 Address allowed");
                return false;
            }
            e.preventDefault();

            var elems = '<div class="col-lg-5"  id="Address' + counter + '">' +
                    '<textarea class="form-control" name="alt_address[]" rows="3" placeholder="Address' + (counter + 1) + '"/><div class="col-lg-6 form-group col-lg-offset-6"> </div>' +
                    '<div class="col-lg-3 form-group" id="city' + counter + '">' +
                    '<select name="city_name[]" id="city_name' + counter + '" class="form-control"><option value="" selected ="selected">Select City</option></select>' +
                    '</div><div class="col-lg-3 form-group"><select name="locality_name[]" id="locality_name' + counter + '" class="form-control"><option value="" selected="selected" >Select Locality</option></select></div></div>' +
                    '<div class="col-lg-1 form-group">' +
                    '<button type="button" class="removebtn" id="removeButton' + counter + '">' +
                    '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span></button>' +
                    '</div><div class="col-lg-6 form-group col-lg-offset-6"> </div>';

            //('#addressDiv').append(elems);
            $('#addressDiv').append(elems);


            $.ajax({
                type: "Post",
                url: "city_load.php",
                success: function (html) {
                    $('#city_name' + counter).html(html);
                }

            });


            $(document).on('change', '#city_name' + counter, function (ev) {

                ev.preventDefault();
                $city_id = $(this).val();

                $.ajax({
                    type: "Post",
                    url: "ajax-dd3ck.php",
                    data: "city_id=" + $city_id,
                    cache: "false",
                    success: function (html) {

                        $('#locality_name' + counter).html(html);

                    }

                });


            });
            //counter++;
            return false;
        });
        $(document).on('click', '.removebtn', function () {

            if (counter == 0)
            {
                alert("No more textbox to remove");
                return false;
            }

            counter--;

            $("#Address" + counter).remove();
            $("#removeButton" + counter).remove();

        });

    });
</script>
```

My PHP Code for adding city in dropdown

**city_load.php:**

```
<?php

include("db.php");
$sql = "select * from city";
echo "<select name='city_name[]' id='city' class='city1'><option value='' selected ='selected'>Select City</option>";
$res = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)) {

    echo "<option value='$row[city_id]'>$row[city_name]</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
?>
```

**locality_load.php**

```
<?php

include("db.php");
$city_id = $_POST['city_id'];

$sql = "select locality_id,locality_name,city_id from locality where city_id=$city_id";

$res = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die("query error");
while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {



    $locality_id = $rows['locality_id'];

    $locality_name = $rows['locality_name'];

    echo "<option value=" . $locality_id . ">" . $locality_name . "</option>";

    //echo '<option value="'.$locality_id.'">'.$locality_name.'</option>';
}
?>
```

The issue I am getting is that the first dynamic div is getting added and data is loading properly but for 2nd dynamic div it is not working.
Please have a look on screenshot:

[image: https://snag.gy/CBXvz.jpg]

Comment: Which part of your code is not working ?

Comment: have you seen any error in console ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var counter = 0;
$(document).on('click', '#addButton', function (e) {
    if (counter > 19) {
        alert("Only 20 Address allowed");
        return false;
    }
    e.preventDefault();

    var $elems = $('<div class="col-lg-5"  id="Address' + counter + '">' +
            '<textarea class="form-control" name="alt_address[]" rows="3" placeholder="Address' + (counter + 1) + '"/><div class="col-lg-6 form-group col-lg-offset-6"> </div>' +
            '<div class="col-lg-3 form-group" id="city' + counter + '">' +
            '<select name="city_name[]" id="city_name' + counter + '" data-index="' + counter + '" class="form-control"><option value="" selected ="selected">Select City</option></select>' +
            '</div><div class="col-lg-3 form-group"><select name="locality_name[]" id="locality_name' + counter + '" class="form-control"><option value="" selected="selected" >Select Locality</option></select></div></div>' +
            '<div class="col-lg-1 form-group">' +
            '<button type="button" class="removebtn" id="removeButton' + counter + '">' +
            '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span></button>' +
            '</div><div class="col-lg-6 form-group col-lg-offset-6"> </div>');

    //('#addressDiv').append(elems);
    $('#addressDiv').append($elems);

    $.ajax({
        type: "Post",
        url: "city_load.php",
        success: function (html) {
            $elelms.find('select').html(html);
        }

    });

    counter++;
    return false;
});
$(document).on('change', 'select', function (ev) {
    var cc = $(this).attr('data-index');
    ev.preventDefault();
    $city_id = $(this).val();

    $.ajax({
        type: "Post",
        url: "ajax-dd3ck.php",
        data: "city_id=" + $city_id,
        cache: "false",
        success: function (html) {
            $('#locality_name' + cc).html(html);
        }
    });
});
$(document).on('click', '.removebtn', function () {

    if (counter == 0)
    {
        alert("No more textbox to remove");
        return false;
    }

    counter--;

    $("#Address" + counter).remove();
    $("#removeButton" + counter).remove();

});
```

});

There are maybe some problem!

Comment: When I was using counter++ the counter was varying in the click event of the dropdown and the data was not coming.is there any other way to make div dynamically with different id's means without counter?

Comment: In ajax callback,u cannot use counter.U can write something like this,var $dom=$('#addressDiv').append(elems);and in ajax callback,use $dom.find('select').html(html).

Comment: I tried it.please have a look on below updated code now:

Comment: We have changed the code as you said.Now on plus click data is binding in city dropdown but whenever click + button again the previous city dropdown again gets populated and slected value gets reset and also locality dropdown value is not going to filledup on selection

Comment: $dom=$('#addressDiv').append(elems);success:function(html){
                $dom.find('.city_name').html(html);
            }

Comment: success:function(html){
    
                $dom.find('.locality_name').html(html);

            }

Answer (score 0):

save the counter value as a data-attr
eg

```
var elems = '<div class="col-lg-5 Address"  data-id="' + counter + '">' +
                '<textarea class="form-control" name="alt_address[]" rows="3" placeholder="Address' + (counter + 1) + '"/><div class="col-lg-6 form-group col-lg-offset-6"> </div>' +
                '<div class="col-lg-3 form-group city" data-id="' + counter + '">' +
                '<select name="city_name[]" data-id="' + counter + '" class="form-control city_name"><option value="" selected ="selected">Select City</option></select>' +
                '</div><div class="col-lg-3 form-group"><select name="locality_name[]" data-id="' + counter + '" class="form-control locality_name"><option value="" selected="selected" >Select Locality</option></select></div></div>' +
                '<div class="col-lg-1 form-group">' +
                '<button type="button" class="removebtn" data-id="' + counter + '">' +
                '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span></button>' +
                '</div><div class="col-lg-6 form-group col-lg-offset-6"> </div>';
```

use a class for each element , bind events on class .
like

```
$(document).on('change','.city_name', function (ev) {
  counter_id = $(this).attr('data-id');
 }
```

so you will get the counter value and hope it will work for every div you created. (code not tested )

Comment: Can you please tell me line after assigning the counter_id , how can i use it in my code.

Comment: address = $(".Address[data-id=counter_id]"); by using this method you can pick each associated datas using counter_id .

Comment: :while applying counter_id = $(this).attr('data-id'); this value is undefined when specify after the line $dom=$('#addressDiv').append(elems);